# dynamically add webbrowsercontrols to form

Tags: vb.net, listbox, dynamic-programming

I have a listbox, this listbox contains numbers. (ID's) A timer should check this listbox every mintue, and for every newly added ID, add a webbrowsercontrol to the Form, with 100% width and hight.. So if for example after 5 Minutes I have 3 Items in the listbox, I need to have 3 Webbrowsercontrols one on top of the other. These webbrowsercontrols need to be called in a way that I recognize which one is what. for example: wbcontrol_*ID* so that I can selectively bring to front the one I currently need. (`wbcontrol_ID.BringToFront()`)  The code also needs to verify that the Webbrowsercontrol has not been generated already, else it will create them over and over again.

This is my code of the timer so far:

```
   Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    fillitemsinlistbox()

    For Each r In ListBox1.Items
      dim mybrowser as new webbrowser

    Next
End Sub
```

And here I am stuck.

Comment: [**`Me.Controls.Add()`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.controlcollection.add(v=vs.110).aspx)?

Comment: thanks, but the question is, how do i give the control a specific name so i can bring it to front when I need it, and how do I check if this control already exists.. THANKS!

Comment: Not to be rude, but have you tried anything? This is generally not the kind of question that suits Stack Overflow. It's also about rather basic programming and you'll find lots of related stuff on Google. If you are using an IDE like Visual Studio you can examine the properties and methods that IntelliSense shows as you type.

Comment: [**`ControlCollection.ContainsKey()`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.controlcollection.containskey(v=vs.110).aspx). I think you can find out quite easily how to change a control's name if you examine [**what properties it contains**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control(v=vs.110).aspx).